# Kendo table width issue - "em" unit

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, width

Does anyone know why column with field "product" shrinks when I changed it's width to "10em"?
http://dojo.telerik.com/OjICaP/16

Comment: $('#grid').kendoGrid({
        columns: [{
          field: 'product',
          locked: true,
          width: "10em",
        }      ////// The column is visible when you set a width to px

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kendo UI, but the [section on locked columns](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#locked-columns) seems to say that the locked column must have a width in pixels.